# Virtual PC to hardware PC

Tags: windows, vmware, virtualization

I know that it is possible to make ordinary PC system virtual and run on virtual machine. For example it is supported by `Vmware`. But now I need somehow place virtual PC to hardware and run it without virtualization software. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Google helps http://www.howtoforge.com/converting-a-vmware-image-to-a-physical-machine-p2 beware of some driver issues...

Comment: Use the same tools that you would generate an image from a physical machine but run the tool within the virtual machine.

Comment: Looks like this clones linux OS. Would be nice to know windows clone expirience

Comment: I'm using vmware, but can't find any option to make physical pc from virtual one